# TraceId using SNS and SQS

Tags: java, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, spring-cloud-sleuth

Good evening!

I receive an SNS inside an SQS Listner, and then I publish another SNS. Inside the SNS that I receive has a TraceId, how can I propagate this trace Id in the SNS that I send?

I thought about using `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth`, but I didn't find any usage example for this scenario.

Can anyone help me or give me some direction?